# How to remove last comma from output from a for loop

Tags: php

The challenge is to write a for loop to print square numbers to the browser that are not divisible by 3. I am not getting the expected output which is
1,4,16,25,49,64,100

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Square Numbers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            for ($a=1;$a<=10;$a++){
                if ($a % 3 != 0){
                    echo $a * $a . ",";
                }
            }
        ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the common technique is to add them to an array, then use `implode` to attach them with glue string ("`,`" for your case). That way there is no need of knowledge when the array is going to end.

```php
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Square Numbers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $values = array();
            for ($a=1;$a<=10;$a++){
                if ($a % 3 != 0){
                    $values[] = $a * $a;
                }
            }
            echo implode(',', $values);
        ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest way is to push the results to an array and then [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it using `,` as the glue on output:

```
$result = [];

for ($a=1;$a<=10;$a++){
    if ($a % 3 != 0){
        $result[] = $a * $a;
    }
}

echo implode(",", $result); // 1,4,16,25,49,64,100
```

Implode joins array elements with the specified string (referred to as the "glue"):

```
implode ( string $glue , array $pieces ) : string
```

You can see it in action [here](https://3v4l.org/Mb1Cl)

Comment: Not sure why this didn't also get an upvote... allow me to fix

Answer (score 1):

A solution without creating an extra array:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Square Numbers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            for ($a=1;$a<=10;$a++){
                if ($a % 3 != 0){
                    echo ($a * $a) . ($a < 10 ? "," : "");
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```